# Progress Bar doesn't update

Tags: vb.net

I I need to have a progress bar while loading the form ; I found this code but it doesn't work ; because the progress bar doesn't update. Someone managed to solve the problem? thanks

```
 Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    For i = 0 To 100
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i)
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    ProgressBar1.Refresh()
End Sub

  Private Sub btnOk_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOk.Click

    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
  Dim form2 As New frm2 ()
  form2.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure it does not work? Because as posted, it should update your progress from 0 to 100 in a split second. Probably not even enough time to blink once.

Comment: Your progress bar is one, too fast, and two, seems to have nothing to do with loading the form.

Comment: How can I slow down the progress bar and make viewable the loading of Form2 ?

Comment: Since you are processing in another thread just use the [System.Threading.Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx) method to introduce a delay.  though doing so will be just arbitrary and not actually referencing any type of progress

Comment: Try using    Progressbar1.Update() instead of Refresh. That will invalidate it and draw() will be called. Also check that ReporteProgress is true and the backgroundworker is not too fast as said before.

Answer (score -3):

Try adding Application.DoEvents to the loop:

```
For i = 0 To 100
    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i)
    Application.DoEvents
next i
```

Comment: Even thought that will work, I would never recommend that **anyone** use DoEvents except in very rare situations.  I have been bit to many times in the past by it.

Comment: I know that there is conjecture about the use of DoEvents. I have used it in situations like this and it has solved the problem without introducing any new ones.

Comment: Since this running in a separate thread I would just use Sleep. Doesn't have the baggage that DoEvents has.

Comment: I hear you. I just recoded a procedure that updates data with a progress bar control displayed. I set it up to run on a separate thread, added some delegates, removed DoEvents from the loop and it worked just fine. Without threading, the progress bar control wouldn't update without DoEvents. In VB6, the use of DoEvents seemed to be widely encouraged. I suspect that the behaviour of DoEvents changed between VB6 and VB.NET. It's use is no longer encouraged as there are other superior means within the framework to achieve the same ends without the baggage that it potentially leaves in its wake.